# Convert Lat and Long to Decimals in R

Tags: r, geolocation

Id like to know how to convert this data set columns

[image: Print of the some rows of the dataset]

Into decimals like these :

-2.93955, -41.32366

The math here is (per exemple for the lat:

(Degrees + Minutes/60 + seconds/3600)*-1 when W or S

which is:

(2+ 56/60 + 22,4/3600)*-1 = -2,93955, same way to calculate the long. Maybe there is a way to not write a function just to do it, but as long i wait i am gonna make this function.

Comment: I guess this might be what you need https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293665/converting-dms-coordinates-to-decimal-in-r

Comment: hello, yeah i saw this question before but doesnt worked for me tks

Comment: Or have you tried `dms2dd`? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/biogeo/versions/1.0/topics/dms2dd

Answer (score 0):

Things that would help for an answer:

Can you produce a reproducible example so that we can understand the content of a cell? If the degrees, minutes, and seconds are all in separate columns, I think your formula above will be fine. If not, you can try the following from the `measurements` package (assuming that degrees and minutes consist of 2 digits each (that is, leading zeroes are present for each)):

`df$lat<-df$lat%>%str_replace_all("(.{2})", "\\1 ")%>%str_trim()
 substr(df$lat,9,9)<-"."
 df$lat<-as.numeric(conv_unit(df$lat,from='deg_min_sec',to='dec_deg'))`

For longitude, just switch `df$lat` for `df$long` and away you go.

**REVISION based on the provided format**

```
   `df$lat<-gsub('°','',df$lat)
    df$lat<-gsub('\'','',df$lat)
    df$lat<-gsub('\\"',"",df$lat)
    df$lat<-gsub('S',"",df$lat)
    df$lat=measurements::conv_unit(df$lat,from = "deg_min_sec",to="dec_deg")`
```

Comment: hi, i updated the question with a print of the data set, there are two columns with lat and long and i wanna plot the location using the leaflet library which needs the loc in decimals